# Trying to download zip file to client browser that was streamed from server in Express

Tags: angular, express, stream, zip

I am using a tool called [s3-zip](https://github.com/orangewise/s3-zip) that zips together files from S3 on the server-side that then streams the zip file to the client using the Express framework.  I can confirm that the code on the server side is working correctly and it is shown below

```
router.get('/download', function (req, res, next) {

    const region = 'us-west-2';
    const bucket = 'my-bucket';
    const folder = 'my-folder/';
    const file1 = '85570334.jpg';
    const file2 = '85570335.jpg';
    const file3 = '85571603.jpg';

    s3Zip
        .archive({ region: region, bucket: bucket}, folder, [file1, file2, file3])
        .pipe(res)
});
```

This is what the response looks like on the chrome console

[image]

The problem is occurring when I am getting the response at the client side and trying to download it as a zip file to the client browser.  I am using the [Angular File Saver](http://alferov.github.io/angular-file-saver/) to do this.  The following snippet is where I am trying to take the response corresponding to the image above and download it to the client browser.

```
var blob = new Blob([res._body], {type: "application/zip"});
FileSaver.saveAs(blob, "test-new.zip");
```

A zip file does get downloaded however when I try to open it on my mac I get the following error

[image]

Can anyone see what is causing this error and how to fix it?

Answer (score 0):

Ah it looks like it was a problem related to the request itself which I did not show in my question.  I added `{responseType: ResponseContentType.Blob }` and it seemed to work after that